# Dockerized python.django app does not run in the browser

Tags: python, django, docker

I have a python-Django app built in ubuntu OS that I am trying to containerize. Docker builds and runs with no errors. But when I try to browse the site in a browser, I do not see it.

This is my allowed hosts in settings.py

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["localhost", "127.0.0.1","0.0.0.0"]
```

And this is my dockerfile

```
#base image
FROM python:3.10

# setup environment variable 
ENV DockerHOME=/home/app

RUN mkdir -p $DockerHOME
WORKDIR $DockerHOME


ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1  

# install dependencies  
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip


# copy the whole project to your docker home directory. 
COPY . $DockerHOME  
# run this command to install all dependencies  

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt  
# port where the Django app runs  
EXPOSE 8000  

# start server  
CMD python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

I tried to run it by the following commands with no luck.

```
sudo docker run -p 8000:8000 myapp:v0
#also the following
sudo docker run myapp:v0
```

I am browsing the site with http://0.0.0.0:8000/
I tried with the docker IP http://172.17.0.2:80000

So not sure what am I missing. Any idea would be very much appreciated.

EDIT:

I have added docker-compose file. This is what I have.

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
build: .
command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
container_name: my_app
volumes:
  - .:/home/app
ports:
  - "8000:8000"
```

And then I tried

```
docker-compose build
docker-compose up -d
```

still do not see the app in browser.
When I run "docker ps", I can see the container ID and status and other things.

Comment: please provide docker-compose file

Comment: dockerfile is used only for to copy your project and requirements not to run your project. docker-compose file is used to create container of your project and then you can run project in docker-compose file

Comment: are you sure your docker is running fine, and not restarting everytime due to error? Check with `docker ps` also you might need to fix your docker group and avoid sudo when running docker.

Comment: @ManojTolagekar You don't need docker-compose to create a container.

Comment: @KlausD why we don't need?

Comment: @ManojTolagekar I do not have a docker compose file. Do I need that? I thought when there is multiple containers, I need a docker compose file. I might be wrong.

Comment: @Ritsard Yes it is running. Hitting those url in the browser does not seem to have any effect in docker.

Comment: @Re.Ho yes you need docker-compose file because in your django project, there are multiple containers, one is your project and another is database so there are multiple containers in your project

Comment: @ManojTolagekar I have added docker-compose.yml. Still not luck. Please see my additions to the original question. Thanks :)

Comment: @Re.Ho I have created dockerfile and docker-compose file for your. Run that and tell me

Answer (score 0):

Here I am creating a new `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose` file based on your project.

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM python:3.9-alpine3.13

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY ./requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt  #here copied requirements.txt into tmp folder

COPY ./your_project_name /app       #here copied your project into app directory
WORKDIR /app                 #This is current working directory
EXPOSE 8000

RUN python -m venv /py && \        #here created venv as py
    /py/bin/pip install --upgrade pip && \
    apk add --update --no-cache postgresql-client jpeg-dev && \
    apk add --update --no-cache --virtual .tmp-build-deps \
        build-base postgresql-dev musl-dev zlib zlib-dev linux-headers && \
    /py/bin/pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt && \

    rm -rf /tmp && \        #here removed tmp folder after installing all the requirements
    apk del .tmp-build-deps && \
    
    mkdir -p /vol/web/media && \           #here created a directory for static and media
    mkdir -p /vol/web/static && \
```

**docker-compose:**

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  app:                 #This is your project container
    build:
      context: .
      args:
       - DEV=true
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
      - dev-static-data:/vol/web
    command: >
      sh -c 'python manage.py migrate &&
             python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000'
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=db #don't change this
      - DB_NAME=add here db name
      - DB_USER=addhere user name
      - DB_PASS=add here password
      - DEBUG=1
    depends_on:
      - db                 #here connected database to project container
  db:
    image: postgres:13-alpine
    volumes:
      - dev-db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=your db name                #here I used postgres as database
      - POSTGRES_USER=your user name
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=your password
volumes:
  dev-db-data:
  dev-static-data:
```

Note: after adding above things don't forget to build dockerfile and docker-compose file.

After building dockerfile and docker-compose, run this project using command `docker-compose up` and then you are able to view this dockerized project in the web browser.

I have created this dockerfile and docker-compose file for you.